# Crystallography - unit cells

Tags: crystallography

According to what I've read, in 2 dimensions, a unit cell is a **parallelogram** whose vertices are all one of the lattice points. In addition we define the conventional cell as the **unit cell** which demonstrate the symmetry properties of a lattice in the best way. Now my question is: why do we consider a hexagon as a conventional cell while its not a parallelogram?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A paved surface covered by consecutive hexagons can also be considered as paved by consecutive lozenges or diamonds, where each lozenge or diamond is made of two small equilateral triangles.

Comment: The primitive cell is also a parallelogram for hexagonal systems: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/162878

Answer (score 0):

In theory, a unit cell can be anything at all in which all pairs of opposite edges and (in three dimensions) are parallel. Among such shapes the parallelogram in two dimensions, or the parallelepiped in three dimensions, is the simplest to drae, to interpret and to do calculations with (e.g. cell volume, number of formula units).